# Qual a melhor maneira de se limpar o buffer do teclado

Tags: c

Já em vi em vários fóruns que se deve utilizar o setbuf(stdin(NULL), ou getchar sou novo em linguagem C e estou com duvida nesse assunto

Comment: Se esta a falar de `setvbuf` tem a ver com *buferização* e não limpar coisas do teclado. Talvez se queira referir a `fflush(stdin)`, mas embora funcione em algumas implementações não é garantido que vai funcionar em todas.

Comment: Eu uso setbuf sempre deu certo, uso por muitas vezes a leitura com espaço entre as string e sempre é necessário limpar os buff ... nunca tive problema com setbuff a principio no seu exemplo tem uma versão mais simplificada de limpar os buff

Answer (score 1):

Os problemas com o buffer do teclado dá se geralmente pela função scanf() ;(Pelo que sei até o momento).

Uma breve descrição desse "problema":

Esse problema só ocorre(posso estar errado) quando queremos que o programa leia um caracter ou um conjunto de caracteres(array do tipo char), pois sempre teremos que dar o enter('\n') para "encerrar" a função scanf e esse enter ficará no buffer de entrada, mas e daí que o enter ficou no buffer de entrada(stdin)? Devemos lembrar que a função scanf sempre lerá o que estiver armazenado no stdin, quando digitamos enter ele "encerra" a função scanf mas continua lá, o proximo scanf(se houver) irá "pegar" esse enter e temos o problema, se testamos esse "erro" lendo inteiros não irá ocorrer pois o enter('\n') não é inteiro.

Irei apresentar duas formas de se resolver esse problema sem adicionar nenhuma função extra no código.

1 - O problema de buffer só ocorre da segunda implementação para frente, logo podemos adicionar um espaço antes do indicator de tipo, scanf(" %c", &caracter);

2 - Adicionar um parâmetro adicional na primeira scanf() que leia um caracter logo após o parâmetro "principal", scanf("%c%*c", &caracter);

No primeiro exemplo eu utilizei um espaço(isso será útil mais adiante como na função sscanf()) pois ele irá ignorar todos os espaços em branco como espaços, enters, tabs. Já no segundo eu usei o * pois ele irá indicar ao programa para ignorar o dado que deveria estar ali(o enter no caso).

Recomendo a leitura deste artigo: https://www.hardware.com.br/comunidade/vicios-devem/1302291/

Para usar todos(ou quase) os benefícios que a função scanf() oferece sugiro a pesquisa sobre scansets.

E minha explicação sobre buffers não é tão boa, pesquise sobre também.

Acho que foi tudo ;)

Acabei de lembrar, nos sites onde li sobre problemas no buffer eles recomendam evitar o uso do fflush() para limpar o buffer de entrada(stdin), pois nesse caso a função fflush() tem comportamento indefinido(segundo os caras que mantém a liguagem).

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/181820)

Comment: Aí está, desculpe por antes não estou acostumado a usar fóruns.

Comment: Como apaga comentários?

Comment: Ao passar o mouse sobre o comentário irá aparecer um `X` para remover após seu nome. Aproveite e leia: [O Stack Overflow em Português é um fórum?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068)

Answer (score 0):

Olha, uma maneira que meu professor utilizava para limpar o buffer do teclado para todos os tipos de leitura era o **fflush(stdin)** e realmente eu te recomendo, por que eu usei muito, e evitava muitos bug quando eu estava lendo do teclado.